# apply function for iterating over dataframe and generating columns based on index column

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, optimization, apply

So let me describe the data:

- *abc* and *xyz* are metrics.
- *hit* is basically the index number, eg:

  - hit value 3 means the corresponding value in abc3 and xyz3
  - hit 4 means abc4, xyz4

Data

```
dat <- data.frame( abc1=c(7, 0, 7), 
                   abc2=c(5, 10, 20), 
                   abc3=c(0, 0, 10), 
                   abc4=c(3, 5, 19), 
                   abc5=c(2, 2, 0), 
                   abc6=c(2, 26, 0),
                   xyz1=c(0, 2, 0),
                   xyz2=c(1, 1, 6),
                   xyz3=c(8, 2, 0),
                   xyz4=c(6, 3, 5),
                   xyz5=c(9, 2, 2),
                   xyz6=c(4, 0, 0),
                   hit=c(3, 4, 4))
```

**What I need to do is find the abc and xyz before hits and after hits.**
The below for loop does the job well for small datasets, but if the data crosses 100k rows, the loop runs seemingly forever.

```
for (c in c('abc','xyz')){
  for (i in 1:nrow(dat)){
    for (m in -2:2){

      dat[[paste(c,'hit', m)]][i] = dat[i,paste(c, dat$hit[i]-m, sep = "")]
    }
  }
}
```

In the output file, 
*'abc hit 0'* for row 1 refers to : hit=3 which in turn picks the value in *abc3* and assigns to *abc hit 0*.

*abc hit -1* translates to hit=3-1=2 which points to *abc2* and *xyz2*

#### I know the 3 for loops are bad idea. Please help me better the code by using apply function or any other way which reduce the execution time.

Comment: Your process would be so much easier if you kept data long  (i.e., one *abc* and one *xyz* column) not wide with suffixed columns. Long is arguably the preferred format of data science facilitating aggregation, merging, plotting, modeling, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to have reversed the 'm' in your for-loop: it runs from -2 to 2, but then you've got `dat$hit - m` - is the subtraction what you wanted? Or should it be `dat$hit + m`?

You could do something like the below - I've not tested it on large datasets but do give it a go:

```
dat1 <- do.call(rbind, 
                lapply(split(dat, 1:NROW(dat)), 
                       function(x) {
                          z <- x[paste0('abc', x$hit + 2:-2)]; 
                          names(z) <- paste0('abc', -2:2); 
                          z 
                       }
                ))
```

The `split` function gives you the rows of the dataframe, happily preserving the column names, on which you can then use the `lapply` function to operate line-by-line.

You can lookup the relevant columns of each line by adding -2 through 2 to `hit`.

Then you bash the resultant list back together into a dataframe.

**Update**:
This is faster than the above by about 30% for 90K rows:

```
dat1 <- t(sapply(split(dat, 1:NROW(dat)), 
                       function(x) unname(x[paste0('abc', x$hit + 2:-2)])  
                ))
dat1 <- as.data.frame(dat1)
colnames(dat1) <- paste0('abc', -2:2)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i will check it out.
Yes, the nature of the dataframe is such that the loop should run in reverse order for m.